# Flutter two ListView.builder inside ListView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, dart

Okey first what I want to get, I want to get two ListView.builder(with physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()) inside ListView which can be scrolled and here is the code how I get that

WORKING CODE!!!

```
      CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text("Artist"),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: maxHeight * 0.014,
                    left: maxWidth * 0.159,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      searchResults1[index].name == null
                          ? Container()
                          : Text(
                              searchResults1[index].name,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // tag: 'recently-played1',
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    child: searchResults1[index].image == null
                        ? Container()
                        : Image(
                            height: maxHeight * 0.0635,
                            width: maxWidth * 0.1306,
                            image: NetworkImage(searchResults1[index].image),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: searchResults1.length
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text("Songs"),
      ),
      SliverList(
        key: list2,
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int i) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: maxHeight * 0.014,
                    left: maxWidth * 0.159,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      searchResults2[i].title == null
                          ? Container()
                          : Text(
                              searchResults2[i].title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                      searchResults2[i].author == null
                          ? Container()
                          : Text(
                              searchResults2[i].author,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: Colors.grey),
                            )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  // tag: 'recently-played1',
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                    child: searchResults2[i].image == null
                        ? Container()
                        : Image(
                            height: maxHeight * 0.0635,
                            width: maxWidth * 0.1306,
                            image: NetworkImage(searchResults2[i].image),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: searchResults1.length
        ),
      ),
    ]);
```

but what is happening here that two lists are long and I have a performance issue, the scroll is not smooth and sometimes even freeze. Something is telling me it's because of **shrinkWrap: true** maybe I'm wrong. The important thing that I want to achieve is that I have Header then one listview.builder then again Header and then last listview.builder.
Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you are using wrong widgets for this purpose. Use a `CustomScrollView` with `SliverList`.

Don't use `shrinkWrap: true` in very long and dynamic lists. to make shrinkWrap to work flutter needs to determine heights of all child widgets of the list this is a heavy computational task. An example of what you can do is

```
CustomScrollView(
 slivers: [
  SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text("some")),
  SliverList(),
  SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text("some")),
 ]
)
```

Comment: I tried this scroll is perfect but the second list always shows error "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..10, inclusive: 11" and when I change places it works but whichever is second it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help I accepted your answer and updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that it is nested views. Instead of using the inner ListView.builder with NeverScrollableScrollPhysics, try using List.generate to populate a column widget. Then the scroll will be handled by your outer ListView. Your inner lists:

```
Column(
      children: List.generate(
          myList,
          (index) => myWidget
```

UPDATE:

Instead of loading an empty image

```
ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
child: searchResults1[index].image == null
? Container()
: Image(
height: maxHeight * 0.0635,
width: maxWidth * 0.1306,
image: NetworkImage(searchResults1[index].image),
fit: BoxFit.cover,
```

Comment: I tried like you say i can tell that scroll is better but when I scroll and somewhere close to second header whole app freeze on few seconds and then I can continue to scroll. Thanks for fast response

Comment: yeah, I will update the question. But I think this error happens because not all images have "Http" in file path?.

Comment: this could be an issue, why dont you try 
`searchResults1[index].image == null
                            ? null
                            : NetworkImage(searchResults1[index].image)),`
So youre not trying to load an empty image

Comment: Sorry, you'd have to do the check before the Image widget, and if its null, return an empty Container()

Comment: Or a container of whatever height you needed

Comment: Same here the error is "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..10, inclusive: 11". any idea